# How can I remove unstoppable link underlines under twentysixteen child themed Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, user-experience

I have [a WordPress site with a twentysixteen child theme](https://cjshayward.com) where I am trying to sharpen certain things. One of the things I want is to make the sidebar less of a speed bump to ideally have the visitor's attention focused on reading the content most of the time.

Some links are underlined on UX motivations. (Embedded links are underlined; lists of links are only underlined on hover.) So second column widgets besides search are candidates to have links usually not be underlined.

**What I have, after something like a dozen attempts, is as follows.** [The stylesheet](https://cjshayward.com/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-ux-tweaks-child/style.css) mostly treats all right column widgets after search as being the same for link underline.

In the UI, if you look at the right column, excluding a widget used to display a column of images:

- The 1st and 3rd widgets, excluding a column of book covers, have links underlined,
- The 2nd and 4th do not.
- The 1st, 2nd, and 3rd use arbitrary text widget.

**I've jumped the shark in debugging.**

I've spent hours turning things on and off in the [style.css](https://cjshayward.com/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-ux-tweaks-child/style.css), adding and subtracting `"text-decoration: none,"` `"text-decoration: underline,"` `"!important,"` etc., and nothing worked.

The snippet below uses the heaviest sledgehammer I could find. The effect I expected would be that I was assigning a `(jQuery.css()) inline !important` style, and that simply couldn't be trumped.

```
;(jQuery(function()
    {
    jQuery.css('aside#secondary a', 'text-decoration: none !important');
    jQuery.css(
      'aside#secondary a:hover', 'text-decoration: underline !important');
    })());
```

I tried in a site JavaScript file and temporarily added the script to footer.php. Nothing. I still have not managed to get the underlines to go away.

I haven't found out what is causing it; I've tried hard enough but am not near to being able to provide a minimal demonstration of the issue; I don't know WordPress's guts.

Thanks,

Comment: You might find an answer on the [WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) exchange, although I would read their [Help Center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) guide first to make sure it's on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that apparently the underline is achieved not with the `text-decoration: underline` css property but with the `box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 currentColor`.

Try override it as follows with css or js:

```
box-shadow: none;
```

Let me know if it helps,